# How can i change the owner/sender of an enveloppe during the signing process?

Tags: docusignapi

I work on the eSignature API, and i wonder if i can change the owner/sender of the envelope during the signing process! For exemple if the owner/sender is in vacation at the end of the process can he be replace ?

And the property of the envelope can be change to be at his name ?

Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is how you do it from the web app:
https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-transfer-envelopes-templates
[image]

The API endpoints are here - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopetransferrules/

We don't yet have code examples for this I'm affraid.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!